# Laravel 7.2.5 Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: php, laravel

I was facing the issue when I do  `php artisan optimize`.
Below is my api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | API Routes |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which | is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API! | */

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

I am confuse & don't know what I am missing.
Already tried following options

1. Delete all cache files
2. Also tried `php artisan cache:clear`
3. Composer update / composer dump-autoload
4. env file changes `CACHE_DRIVER=file`,`SESSION_DRIVER=database`

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Use a controller/method instead of the function

Comment: @brombeer Thanks! Controller works !. But my actual question is why function method not working...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check Laravel's optimize command:

```
    /**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->call('config:cache');
    $this->call('route:cache');

    $this->info('Files cached successfully!');
}
```

There is a line `$this->call('route:cache');`
This line is throwing the error.

Laravel is trying to cache the routes. It does not accept Closure while caching the route. That's why moving your code to a controller fixed the issue.